# Adding and removing classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery snippet written where if any of my inputs in a specific table are entered it changes the class of the rest of the inputs on that table, but if the user fills in an input field, and then deletes their input it still changes the class, though it shouldnt.  here is my attempt at doing this.

```
 $('#lostTable :input').change(function(){                                          

        var $lostTableInput = $('#lostTable :input:not(input[type=hidden])');
        var hasData = false;

        $lostTableInput.each(function(){
            if($(this).val().length > 0){
                hasDataLf = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

    $lostTableInput.toggleClass('R', hasDataLf); 

// this above part works for changing the class, and below is my attempt at changing
// it back if the user deletes the data that was entered in.

    $lostTableInput.each(function(){
      if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $lostTableInput.removeClass('R'); 
    }
   }
  )
 }
);
```

Comment: You declare the variable as "hasData", but then you actually use "hasDataLf" ... which is it supposed to be?

Comment: So when any `<input>` changes, you find all the inputs, and if any one of them has a non-empty value, you add class "R" to all of them. Then, you want to go through and remove "R" from the class of any one that's empty.  Seems like you could do this much more simply ...

Comment: @Pointy , weird I never noticed that...interesting that it still ran.  It should be hasDataLf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify a bit...

```
var $inputs =  $('#lostTable :input').not(':hidden');
$inputs.change(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('dummy', $(this).val().length > 0);
  $inputs.toggleClass('R', $inputs.filter('.dummy').length > 0);
});
```

You may want to look into the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) jquery method, for better performance. And you may want a better name than 'dummy' for the dummy class ;)

Comment: Yes, i tried that as well, but the OP only wants to remove the class if there is **no** input in any of the `input`s

Comment: Edited to take that into account. Thanks @Neal.

Comment: @sje , thanks for the answer....this is a little complicated for my slight knowledge of jQuery, though. And when I copied the code to try it, it didnt add the class if the inputs were selected....is there anything from my code that still needs to be in there?

Comment: @Jonathon - The idea is, it will add the 'dummy' class to any input that contains anything...then look to see if any input has the dummy class, and if so, add the 'R' class to all the inputs.

Comment: I did a fiddle here that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/e7TzS/ ... you might want to toggle the function on the body/keydown if you want it to happen on keypresses rather than on field value changes (which are notified when the field loses focus).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to go through all the values. You are looking on change of one input:

```
$('#lostTable input').change(function() {
    var $lostTableInput = $('#lostTable input').not(':hidden');
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $lostTableInput.toggleClass('R', true);
    }
    else if (this.value.length == 0 || this.value == null) {
        var found_one = false;
        $lostTableInput.each(function(index, item) {
            if (item.value.length > 0) {
                found_one = true;
                return false;
            }
        })
        if (!found_one) {
            $lostTableInput.removeClass('R');
        }
    }
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYrqx/

Comment: hmmm...unless I copied incorrectly, I could not get this to work.  It did not toggle the class when I entered a particular input field.

Comment: `.change` is on exit. try using `keyup` instead of `change`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do:

```
if(!hasDataLf){ // if every field is empty this should have remained false
   $lostTableInput.removeClass('R'); 
}
```

Comment: It makes sense to do it this way, but it does not work when I try it.  It is like the input fields still think that there is data in their field.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the comparator, try:

`if ($(this).val() == null)
{
   $lostTableInput.removeClass('R'); 
}`